# UIScrollView with glitch content on iPhone 11 Pro Max

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I’m new in Swift and I tried making `UIScrollView` that shows view controllers.

Every thing perfect just at iPhone 11 Pro Max the next screen show a little bit on the side:

[the orange strip is the next screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgAJd.png)

My Code:

```
//MARK: - outlets

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

//MARK: - properties

var viewControllers: [String] = ["ComputerViewController", "AttactViewController", "DefenceViewController", "OfflineViewController"]
var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

//MARK: - life cyrcles
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    for index in 0..<viewControllers.count {
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)

        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size


        let view = UIView(frame: frame)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Menu", bundle: nil)
        var controller: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllers[index]) as UIViewController

        view.addSubview(controller.view)


        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)

    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(viewControllers.count), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

    scrollView.delegate = self

}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width

    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

thanks for helping...

Comment: You will have several problems with this approach... but first, have you looked at using a `UIPageViewController`? It has all that functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. You should avoid referencing `frame` in `viewDidLoad`. At this point, the `frame` is not known.
2. You should avoid hard-coding the size and placement of the subviews at all. There can be a variety of events that change the view’s size later on (e.g. rotations, split view multitasking, etc.). Use constraints.
3. With scroll views, there are two layout guides, one for its `frame` and another for its `contentSize`. So set the size of the subviews using the `frameLayoutGuide` and the placement of these subviews relative to the `contentLayoutGuide`.
4. When you add a view controller’s `view` as a subview, make sure you call `addChild(_:)` and `didMove(toParent:)` calls for view controller containment. See “Implementing a Container View Controller” section of the [view controller documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller).
5. If you want to add paging behavior, just set `isPagingEnabled` of the scroll view.

Pulling that all together:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addChildViews()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var anchor = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor

    for identifier in viewControllers {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let child = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
        addChild(child)                   // containment call
        child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)     // containment call

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // define size of child view (relative to `frameLayoutGuide`)

            child.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
            child.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor),

            // define placement of child view (relative to `contentLayoutGuide`)

            child.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchor),
            child.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            child.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        anchor = child.view.trailingAnchor
    }
    anchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
}
```

I’ve eliminated the property `frame` as that’s not needed anymore (and is just a source of confusion with the view controller’s view’s property of the same name). I’ve also eliminated the container view as it didn’t add much to the overall solution (and only adds a layer of constraints to add).

But the key is to use constraints to dictate the size and position of the subviews within the scroll view and to use view controller containment API.

Comment: first of all thank a lot for the helping, its fix the problem but now have new issue:
he shrink my view height.

Before:
https://imgur.com/xJGV1bh

After:
https://imgur.com/Ia1jyu8

THANKS

Comment: @LiorD - It looks like you haven’t defined the vertical constraints between the scroll view and its super view (e.g. the bottom of the scroll view and whatever is below it). But that’s unrelated to the code above, which assumes you’ve defined the height of the scroll view and are only worried about configuring the subviews/pages inside that scroll view.